# Javascript Function to add Event not working

Tags: javascript, html, function, class, addeventlistener

I just noticed this. It's a lil weird but I don't know if I'm forgetting to do something or it's just something that won't work.
I'm trying to add an Event on an element in these two separate ways. The first works but the second doesn't. Someone kindly go through please

(Snippet A)... //This adds the event to the input tag and works fine in most browsers

```
    for (var j = 0, inp = _T("input");j < inp.length;j++) {
       var place, value;
       inp[j].classList.contains("inp") ? inp[j].onblur = inp[j].onfocus = function() {
       this.placeholder != "" ? (value = this.value, place = this.placeholder, this.placeholder = "", this.value = value) : this.placeholder = place;
       this.className.indexOf("swell")>0 ? rC(this, "swell") : aC(this, "swell");
       }:0
    }
```

(Snippet B)... //This doesn't work in any browser but I need it to cos of compatibility issues

```
    for (var j = 0, inp = _T("input");j < inp.length;j++) {
       var place, value;
       inp[j].className.indexOf("inp") > 0 ? inp[j].onblur = inp[j].onfocus = function() {
       this.placeholder != "" ? (value = this.value, place = this.placeholder, this.placeholder = "", this.value = value) : this.placeholder = place;
       this.className.indexOf("swell") > 0 ? rC(this, "swell") : aC(this, "swell");
       }:0
    }

//_T("input") = document.getElementsByTagName
```

I'm stuck in the middle of a serious project and minor issues like this can just be frustrating.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I literally get no errors. When I inspect the element in firefox, I notice the event is not added on the tag in the case of snippet B but does in snippet A

Comment: Where are this two statements being used? The two code snippets look to be identical so if one works any errors should be contextual.

Comment: @CalebB Difference `inp[j].className.indexOf("inp")` and `inp[j].classList.contains("inp")`

Comment: @CalebB Ok. say you have `window.onload= function(){//snippets in here}`. A adds the event, B doesn't

Comment: .classList does not have a .contains() method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Why does this question have the `addEventListener` tag when you're only using old-fashioned `.on...` events?

Comment: Javascript Array doesn't naturally have a contains function however you can append one to the array prototype at the top of your file as such `Array.prototype.contains = function(value) { //loop to loop for value in 'this' };` then you can use contains in any js array object.

Comment: @Lil Devil Snippet A even works in firefox.Meaning classList.contains() runs. I had to change to the old-fashioned way for comprehension purposes

Comment: Also something to note is if `inp` is not in className it will return -1 not 0 so if className starts with `inp` it will resolve to false since the index of 'inp' would be 0.

Comment: @CalebB By array, you mean the inp array? signifying the inp[j].classList.contains?

Comment: I'm talking about standard javascript array objects in general. There isn't a 'contains' function but you can add one as I illustrated above.

Comment: @CalebB Thanks so much for your last indication about the index of "inp" class... That actually solved it.

Comment: No problem, happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indexOf will return 0 if it is the first element. So if "inp" is present but it is the first part (element 0), it will not be greater than zero.

Comment: I guess I should add: indexOf returns -1 when it doesn't find what it's looking for, so you should change the > 0 to > -1 and it should work.